Controller Service Repository Error handling
I am currently working on a ASP.NET 8 MVC project where we decided to use the Controller-Service-Repository pattern.
At the moment there is not a lot of business logic yet in the MVC Service layer, so mostly it calls the repository and nothing else.
The repository calls an API. This is a SOAP API, so I cannot rely on HTTP errors there. I only get a "Code" where 0 is OK.
A lot of API methods have rather complex business logic, so it is a lot of work to implement the same logic in the MVC Service layer, if not impossible because we simple cannot get all the data from the API. So we rely on the API mostly for business logic errors.
When I believe there is an error in the API I throw a RepositoryException.
Then however I am uncertain what would be the best approach to send this to the client.
Should I handle repository exceptions in the Service layer with a try catch and then throw an ServiceException (which does not exist yet)?
Should I then do the same thing (try catch) to the Controller and send this to the View?
I could use some advice on how to handle this in an elegant way.
The SoapClient:
public static IServiceCollection AddSoapClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISoapService>(options =>
    {
        string uri = "Some API URL";

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 67108864; // 64 megabytes
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);

        if (uri.ToLower().StartsWith("https"))
        {
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        }

        return new SoapServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
    });

    return services;
}

The repository:
public class ContactPersonRepository : SoapRepository, IContactPersonRepository
{
    public ContactPersonRepository(ISoapService client, ISoapAuthentication authentication) : base(client, authentication)
    {
    }

    public async Task<ContactPerson> UpdateAsync(ContactPerson contactPerson)
    {
        var response = await client.UpdateContactPersonAsync(DeviceId, AuthToken, contactPerson);

        if (response.HasErrors())
        {
            throw new SoapRepositoryException(response);
        }

        return response.ContactPerson;
    }
}

The HasErrors() class is an extension method which simply filters out errors by Code. For example, Code 2 means that there are no results in the list. I don't see this as a real error and ignore it.
The Extension method HasErrors():
public static class ServiceResponseExtensions
{
    public static bool HasErrors(this ServiceResponse response)
    {
        int[] errorCodeWhitelist = [0, 1, 2, 10];

        return !errorCodeWhitelist.Contains(response.Error);
    }
}

The Service:
public class ContactPersonService : IContactPersonService
{
    private IContactPersonRepository contactPersonRepository;

    public ContactPersonService(IContactPersonRepository contactPersonRepository)
    {
        this.contactPersonRepository = contactPersonRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ContactPerson> UpdateAsync(ContactPerson contactPerson)
    {
        try
        {
            return await contactPersonRepository.UpdateAsync(contactPerson);
        }
        catch(RepositoryException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }
}

The Controller:
public class ContactPersonController : BaseController
{
    private IContactPersonService contactPersonService;

    public ContactPersonController(IContactPersonService contactPersonService)
    {
        this.contactPersonService = contactPersonService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ContactPersonEditModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ContactPerson toUpdate = model.MapTo<ContactPerson>();

            try
            {
                await contactPersonService.UpdateAsync(toUpdate);
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(ServiceException ex)
            {
                AddMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}


Can you tell me which  dependencies you use about  SOAP?

Added the dependency that is injected to the original message. The class SoapServiceClient comes from the WCF Web service reference (Created from Visual Studio).
